# how to select multiple items using the AND operator

Tags: mysql

Here is my `employe` table

```
mysql> select * from employe;
+------+------+------------+---------------------+------+------+------+
| ENO  | ENOM | PROF       | DATAEMB             | SALL | COMM | DNO  |
+------+------+------------+---------------------+------+------+------+
|   10 | Joe  | Ingenieur  | 2020-03-06 18:24:46 | 4000 | 3000 |    3 |
|   20 | Jack | Technicien | 2020-03-06 18:24:46 | 3000 | 2000 |    2 |
|   30 | Jim  | Vendeur    | 2020-03-06 18:24:46 | 5000 | 5000 |    1 |
|   40 | Lucy | Ingenieur  | 2020-03-06 18:24:46 | 5000 | 5000 |    3 |
|   50 | Joe  | Ingenieur  | 2020-03-07 13:47:24 | 4000 | 3000 |    3 |
|   60 | Jack | Technicien | 2020-03-07 13:47:24 | 3000 | 2000 |    3 |
|   70 | Jim  | Vendeur    | 2020-03-07 13:47:24 | 5000 | 5000 |    3 |
+------+------+------------+---------------------+------+------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I want to select the department that contains the three professions the department which has as profession Ingenieur(Engineer), (Technicien) Technician and (Vendeur) seller
my `sql` request

```
SELECT DNO as DEPTOUTPROF FROM employe WHERE(PROF = "Ingenieur" and PROF = "Technicien" and PROF = "Vendeur") ;
```

I expect to have `3` but it shows me `Empty set (0.00 sec)` and i don't know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query as it is will always return 0 rows . `PROF` field cannot be equal to 3 different values at the same time . 
You need something similar to

```
select dno 
from employe 
where prof in ('Ingenieur','Technicien','Vendeur') 
group by dno
having count(distinct prof) =3 ;
```

There are couple more ways to get what you want, you may try them and find which one has better performance .